# IntelliJ insert blank line before last '}' in class files

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I've been trying to find the option of inserting a blank line before the closing '}' of the class and have not found it.

My goal is to format

```
interface IShooter {

    void incHealth(); // health++

    void decHealth(); // health--

    int getHealth();
}
```

to this

```
interface IShooter {

    void incHealth(); // health++

    void decHealth(); // health--

    int getHealth();

}
```

Comment: out of curiosity, why? and what benefit do you gain from that?

Comment: I think this is for symmetry.

Comment: *Put the opening `{` on a separate line and you have your symmetry without newlines*

Comment: @njzk2 obviously it will have no benefit. I just prefer that style of coding and makes code consistent and cleaner.

Comment: No but seriously, is there something I can do to achieve this? Instead of manually inserting a blank line below the last method.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is not possible with stock IntelliJ. If you open up Preferences > Editor > Code Style > Java and then click the Blank Lines Tab.
you can see a list of options.

As you can see, there is an option for Maximum Blank Lines **Before '}'**
but unfortunately not for Minimum Blank Lines.

[image]

**UPDATE**:

"Before class end" option was added to "Minimum Blank Lines".

Available since 2018.2 - [Youtrack Ticket](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-57898)

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Settings > Editor > Code Style > Java -> Blank Lines Tab

Before class end: 1

[image: Preview]

Comment: This feature is available since 2019.1